# How do a write formula to calculate based on multiple cell values?

Tags: excel, formula

I need to calculate some numbers based on data entered into a spreadsheet.
The data is entered in multiple cells and then a value output based on the entered data.

I want to be able to share input data in A5 divide by 2.2 the value of thus then needs to be checked and if its 30 or below multiply by 40 if between 30 and 55, multiply by 35 and if 55 or up multiply by 30.

divide that sum by 28.3

so far i have

```
=SUM(A5/2.2)=IF(AND(B5>55,B5<30),TOTAL(*30,*40)
```

Which does not work at all and is missing some of the variables because i have no idea how to add them in as i cant get the first bit to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CHOOSE/MATCH:

```
=A5/2.2*CHOOSE(MATCH(A5/2.2,{0,30,55}),40,35,30)/28.3
```

Comment: Forgot about `CHOOSE`. Great answer

Answer (score 2):

You should probably read up on how to use Excel formulae.

```
=IF(A5/2.2<=30,40*A5/2.2,IF(A5/2.2<55,35*A5/2.2,30*A5/2.2))/28.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Different ways to approach this. What I did was in `B5`, I set the following:

```
=SUM($A$5/2.2)
```

Then in `C5`, I had the following formula:

```
=IF($B$5<= 30, $B$5 * 40, IF(AND($B$5>30, $B$5 <=55), $B$5 * 35, $B$5 *30))/28.3
```

Comment: Thank you but data needs to also be input in B5 so i cannot put a formula in it

Comment: No Problem. You have other answers to choose rom :)

Comment: It doesn't have to be in B5.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shortened version of other answers posted.

```
=IF(A5/2.2<=30,40,IF(A5/2.2<55,35,30))*A5/(2.2*28.3)
```

Comment: Thanks how do i add in if between 30 and 55, multiply by 35 there were 3 variables but i can only see 2 in the formula. It works though but i just need to add the between 30 and 55 variable

Comment: That logic is already present in this formula. You can use 2 IF statements to compare 3 conditions.